# join 2 tables with extra maths

Tags: mysql

I am writing a database for a quiz module. There are two tables one for teams and one for submitted data. The teams are able to play a joker in one round only and get their scores doubled for that round.

So the teams table has a filed fldJoker that is an int and can be 1 to 8.

The data table contains a teamid (who submitted it), plus a round number and a score.

When I calculate the total scores, I want to double the scores in the round that had the joker played, and this is the sticking point for me.

Could anyone give me any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
select teamid, sum(score * if(fldJoker = round, 2, 1)) ...
```

Comment: Awesome...thanks so much! The only problem was the == needed to be a single =  Thanks for your help!